# CS0012 Error when building the getting started Xamarin Android app

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.android

I am following along with the getting started tutorial:

> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-android-get-started-preview/

I can successfully work the steps up through "Publish your server project to Azure".  However, when I download, open and build the `Xamarin.Android` app I have issues.  Specifically, the output window says the build was successful, but the error window indicates that there are 14 errors, all of which are `CS0012`.

I understand that the "System.Runtime" assembly isn't being referenced, but no solutions I have been able to identify on `MSDN` or on `StackExchange` seem to correct the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue, plus a number of others (related to missing references) by adding the references using the "server" portion of the getting started demo. I also had to update all of the nugget packages as the references I added were in conflict with some of the existing references in the project.